# ¿Por qué funciona el break y no el continue en un switch?

Tags: c

No entiendo bien por qué me funciona con el `break` y no con el `continue`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char palabra[24];
    char aux[24];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Palabra: ");
    fgets(palabra, sizeof(palabra), stdin);

    if (strlen(palabra) > 0 && palabra[strlen(palabra) - 1] == '\n') {
        palabra[strlen(palabra) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    strcpy(aux, palabra);

    while (palabra[i] != '\0') {
        switch (palabra[i]) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                palabra[i] = '-';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("La palabra %s es %s\n", aux, palabra);

    return 0;
}
```

Lo que no entiendo es que al final del bloque `switch`, cuando uso `default` me funciona bien cuando uso `break` y no cuando uso `continue`.
Yo tengo entendido que ambos, `continue` y `break`, te hacen salir automáticamente del bucle.
Y si este fuera el caso, se saltaría el paso de `i++`.

¿Por qué me funciona con `break` y no con `continue`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los `break` dentro de un `switch` los toma el `switch`. En ese caso, siempre llegas a la línea de `i++`. Sin embargo, `switch` ignora el uso de `continue` porque no le pertenecen, entonces le llega al `while`. Esto último hace que al caer en la condicion de `default` dentro del `switch` se ejecute el `continue` dentro del `while` y nunca se llegue a la sentencia `i++`.

Cuando usas `continue` en tu ejemplo, si la letra es una vocal, entonces modificas ese caracter y pasas a la siguiente letra con `i++`. Pero al llegar a una letra que no es vocal, llegas al `default` del `switch`, se ejecuta el `continue` del `while`, y comienza otro loop **sobre la misma letra**. El código quedaría en un loop infinito.

Comment: impecable, mil gracias por la ayuda.